# Deploying Easyrtc server to azure

Tags: azure, easyrtc

I recently tried using **easyrtc** on a project. It worked pretty well on my local pc and everything seemed fine. But deploying it to azure has been a serious problem.

I have tried uploading the exact installation from my pc. It actually works, because i debugged with **azure cli**, but I get an internal server error and when i try to connect I keep getting

> ERR:CONNECTION_TIMEOUT

and some other errors.

Please has anybody done this before and are there any pointers to help me deploy this successfully. Thank you.

Comment: You really haven't provided any specific details, so it would just be guesses at this point. We don't know how you deployed (Linux VM? Windows VM? Web/worker role? Azure Web App?). We don't know if you've attempted to open external ports. We don't know... anything, other than a single error.

Comment: Ok, i deployed a Nodejs app using Azure Web App. I have websockets enabled and other necessary things because i have been able to connect to socket.io in the past via thesame means.